# php link between td if file exists

Tags: php, file, if-statement, hyperlink, html-table

i am trying add a link to my search results 
but i want that to check if the file exists before adding the link
i want that to be something like that.

```
 echo'<tr>
<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:50px; align:"left";>'.$result["BASECODE"].'

<?php
if (file_exists("images/'.$result["BASECODE"].'.png")) 
{
echo "<a href="images/'.$result["BASECODE"].'.png">img</a>";
}
?>
</td>

<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:50px;align:"left";>'.$result["KNITTYPE"].'</td>
<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:250px;align:"left";>'.$result["COMPOSITION"].'</td>
<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:100px;align:"left";>'.$result['REALWEIGHT'].'</td>
<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:100px;align:"left";>'.$result["REALWIDTH"].'</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you opened a new php statement while the last `echo` command is still open. Moreover, you seem to incorrectly using quotes and single quotes. The correct way, using your original code as reference, is:

```
echo '<tr>
<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:50px; align:"left";>'.$result["BASECODE"];

if (file_exists('images/' . $result["BASECODE"] . '.png')) {
  echo '<a href="images/'.$result["BASECODE"].'.png">img</a>';
}

echo '</td>

<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:50px;align:"left";>'.$result["KNITTYPE"].'</td>

<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:250px;align:"left";>'.$result["COMPOSITION"].'</td>

<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:100px;align:"left";>'.$result['REALWEIGHT'].'</td>

<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:100px;align:"left";>'.$result["REALWIDTH"].'</td>
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo'<tr>
<td style=font-family:Gadugi;font-size:16px; width:50px; align:"left";>'.$result["BASECODE"].'
if (file_exists("images/'.$result["BASECODE"].'.png")) 
{
echo "<a href="images/'.$result["BASECODE"].'.png">img</a>";
}
</td>
```

your are using php start and end inside php